# How do I multiply two discrete distributions together?

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, bayesian, discrete-data

As part of my PhD research, I am simulating a system that comprises multiple sensors, and I want to perform sensor fusion. My sensors give me sets of measurements (values between 0 and 1 mm) that I want to combine using Bayes Theorem to get a posterior distribution, hence I can make inferences about the whole system performance.

The datasets look like this (in Matlab notation):

Sensor1 = [0.56, 0.49, 0.55, 0.62, 0.43, ...];

Sensor2 = [0.62, 0.72, 0.53, 0.59, 0.60, 0.70, ...];

Things to keep in mind:

- Datasets are of varying sizes.
- They don't necessarily come from normal distributions, hence I cannot multiply gaussians.
- I don't have the functions that the data came from, I only have the data.

Treating 2 datasets as likelihood functions and assuming a prior of unity (i.e., assuming no prior knowledge), I end up in a position to multiply these two distributions, given Bayes theorem, p(posterior) ~ p(prior) x p(likelihood) (please excuse my casual way of writing this).

Under another question asked on Stack Exchange, a user stated that "...Bayesian evidence combination is done by pointwise product of densities in the continuous case, the pointwise product of masses in the discrete case, etc. This is called product of experts by Geoff Hinton". Hence, I attempted obtaining a histogram of the datasets' probabilities, where I define common bins for the datasets. Then I tried multiplying the probabilities in the same bins together, which gave me a posterior probability distribution.

This is as far as I got. I cannot find any reliable sources backing the claim in quotation marks in the previous paragraph, hence I cannot be sure if my method will be accepted/valid.

Any advice on how I can tackle this problem, or links to reliable sources that I can use to back what I did here would be much appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Best,
Dom

Comment: They can't be normal since their domain is (0,1)